# Charles Proxy Map Local

Tags: reverse-proxy, charles-proxy, tealium

I want to "switch off" a legacy tag management tool and replace it with a new tag manager.

Therefore, I want to map a local .js file to set up a tag testing environment.

However, Charles only shows me unknown paths (packages) and therefore I cannot map a local file.

Any clue what setting might cause this issue?

Comment: Is this an SSL site by any chance? If so, you would need to configure SSL proxying in Charles: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/. You will also need to install the Charles SSL cert in your keychain. For SSL sites, Charles can only show you the domain name if you haven't enabled SSL proxying.

Comment: It is a SSL site. 
I also installed the SSL cert and enabled the SSL Proxying. 
These are the steps you proposed, right?
Still, the content remains <unknown> and there are no folders I can map.

Comment: Did you add a rule to enable ssl proxying for your specific domain? You can also use * as a wildcard for all domains.

Comment: Found out the issue!
The SSL cert was installed in the keychain, but in an "unsafe" folder. 
Put the cert to a safe location and trusted it in Chrome and now it worked!
Thanks a lot!